# How to put a Modal Box inside of a DataTable using Jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, modal-dialog

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a Modal Box popup in DataTables but I'm having a bunch of trouble with it. I basically copied the example code given from https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/jqueryui-modal.html and everything but the button for the modal box is displaying.

[Data Tables Example w/ Modal Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRbfq.png)

[My copied example of their code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZiLl.png)

Also, for some reason doing the .DataTable script in the html file seemed to work better than putting it in it's own .js file and linking that at the end of the body for some reason?

Any help understanding where I'm going wrong would be great. Or, different ways to implement it would be cool too. Thanks all!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.jqueryui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.jqueryui.min.css">

  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                    header: function ( row ) {
                        var data = row.data();
                        return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                    }
                } ),
                renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll()
            }
        }
    } );
} );</script>
 </head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>6224</td>
                <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
                <td>9497</td>
                <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I test your code, it works the same way the DataTables example does. What specifically is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example and the example on the DataTables page perform in the same way. It's not clear what is wrong. You may consider loading the CSS before the JS libraries.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
          header: function(row) {
            var data = row.data();
            return 'Details for ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1];
          }
        }),
        renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll()
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.jqueryui.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.jqueryui.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn</td>
      <td>Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
      <td>9497</td>
      <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Odd,  I'm using vs code to show a live preview of it on chrome.  And the second photo I have linked is what I see,  without the green plus on the left.

Comment: Oh, @Twisty so, when I run your code snippet I see that it runs correctly. However, when I hit the thing to go to the full page, it breaks it.So, when I shrink the screen down to a certain size it re-enables the green circle again. Any idea why size would break it?

Comment: Okay, actually after playing around with it a bit, I see that when it resizes itself it either adds or removes the columns. Then if it removes more than one column, it adds the modal box...funky.

Comment: Will a modal only show completely on top of the `example` datatable if you use the `Responsive` object within the jquery library?  I created a `div` modal with a css class that has the `display: none` attribute.  As in your example I click on a row and a jquery function gets the `closest` row data to the click event and populate my modal then set the `display: block`.  But what differs from your example is the modal does not appear on top of the `example` table, but beneath as if the `overflow: hidden`.  Do you maybe have a solution on how to make a modal visible on top of a jquery datatable?

Comment: Solved my own question:  I just had to set the `z-index: 1` of my modal.